# Possible use case of a function's name property in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can some one explain me what can be use case of function's name property in Javascript?, I read that it can be helpful in recursion, how ?

```
function foo() {}
foo.name; // "foo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a use case from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

You can use `obj.constructor.name` to check the "class" of an object

```
function a(){
}

var b = new a();
alert(b.constructor.name); //Alerts "a"
```

Think of it the as using `get_class()` in PHP or `.getClass().getName()` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of much of a use case, as it's read only. But it is described on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

I can only imagine you might want to use it in `eval` type situations.